Sheaf cohomology of non-paracompact manifolds (e.g. the long line)
I have long heard that manifolds are "affine". If we allow non-paracompact manifolds, then this seems to fail, since as explained in Dmitri Pavlov's answer, the Serre–Swan theorem fails. I wonder to what extent it could be compared with the non-affineness in algebraic geometry? For example, as an analogue of "coherent" coefficients in algebraic geometry,

(cf. Serre vanishing) Does the higher cohomology of the sheaf $\underline{\mathbb R}:=C(-,\mathbb R)$ of real-valued continuous functions vanish on non-paracompact Hausdorff manifolds?

On the other hand, as an analogue of étale coefficients in algebraic geometry,

(cf. Artin vanishing) What is the cohomological dimension of non-paracompact Hausdorff manifolds? Or rather, if we only look at local systems of abelian groups, is the cohomology bounded by the dimension of the non-paracompact Hausdorff manifold?

I would be happy to see references for these. If they are too hard for the moment, I would also be glad to hear anything about the very example of the long line.

Update: As R. van Dobben de Bruyn and Dmitri Pavlov mentioned, for non-paracompact manifolds, the sheaf cohomology with coefficients in constant sheaves is equivalent to the singular cohomology, due to a theorem by Sella. This is also covered in Dustin Clausen's Lecture notes on algebraic de Rham cohomology, Lecture 3, Theorem 12. It might extend to local systems as well. And for singular cohomology, if I understand correctly, we do have the vanishing result.

Related: in case of the long line, it is still true that $H^i(X,\underline{A}) = 0$ for any $A \in \mathbf{Ab}$ and any $i>0$. This uses some sort of 'long homotopy invariance' argument; see e.g. Bredon's Sheaf theory, chapter II, exercise 3 (solution in Appendix B). But this does not say much about the sheaf $C^0(-,\mathbf R)$. (For manifolds, note that both the proof that $C^0(-,\mathbf R)$ is soft and the proof that soft sheaves are acyclic use the paracompactness hypothesis.)

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn Could you please briefly explain what this "long homotopy invariance" is? The book is under paywall and inaccessible to me.

@Z.M: By a theorem of Sella, the sheaf cohomology of a locally contractible space (such as the long line) with coefficients in an abelian group coincides with its singular cohomology.  See https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06927v3

Can you get anything from the fact that $M$ is locally compact?

@DmitriPavlov Oh right, that's also true. The locally contractible case (as opposed to cohomologically locally connected) was already known prior to Sella; see for instance Voisin's Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry I (Theorem 4.47).

@Z.M although Dmitri Pavlov gave a better argument, let me add some details. Homotopy invariance is proved using the proper base change theorem plus the fact that $[0,1]$ is acyclic. Replacing $[0,1]$ by the closed long ray $[0,\omega_1]$, you can run the same argument for $h \colon X \times [0,\omega_1]\to X$ such that $h(-,0)=*$ and $h(-,\omega_1)=\operatorname{id}$, assuming $[0,\omega_1]$ is acyclic. Bredon argues that any compact totally ordered space with the order topology is acyclic. A long homotopy $[0,\omega_1)\times [0,\omega_1]\to [0,\omega_1)$ could be $(a,b)\mapsto\min(a,b)$.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn Let me check: non-paracompact manifolds are locally of singular shape, thus even local systems are the same as local systems on the singular complex. In particular, this seems to imply the Artin vanishing for local systems. Do I understand correctly?

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn In addition, the homotopy invariance that you mentioned has an exodromic generalization in Thm 0.2 of Haine–Porta–Teyssier, which says that the category of locally hyperconstant sheaves in strongly homotopy invariant in the sense that, the projection $X\times Y\to X$ induces a categorical equivalence for every weakly contractible and locally weakly contractible spaces $Y$ (which contains the long line as a special case).

Ah, thanks for the pointer; I was vaguely aware of that paper but didn't actually read it. Yes, I think what you said sounds right to me.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn There is also a more recent paper by Porta–Teyssier which generalizes the topological exodromy to non-paracompact not-necessarily-locally-of-singular-shape spaces in the same fashion (Thm 1.4 & Cor 1.5). Maybe something like this works for perfectoid spaces as well.
